# deref an atom after recursive function completes

Tags: recursion, clojure, atomic

I have an atom `fs` that I'm updating inside a recursive function `freq-seq` that's the value that holds the results of my computation. I have another function `mine-freq-seqs` to start `freq-seq` and when `mine-freq-seqs` is done I would like to receive the last value of said atom. So I thought I would do it like so

```
(ns freq-seq-enum)

(def fs (atom #{}))

(defn locally-frequents
  [sdb min-sup]
  (let [uniq-sdb (map (comp frequencies set) sdb)
        freqs (apply merge-with + uniq-sdb)]
    (->> freqs
         (filter #(<= min-sup (second %)))
         (map #(vector (str (first %)) (second %))))))


(defn project-sdb
  [sdb prefix]
  (if (empty? prefix) sdb
                      (into [] (->> sdb
                           (filter #(re-find (re-pattern (str (last prefix))) %))
                           (map #(subs % (inc (.indexOf % (str (last prefix))))))
                           (remove empty?)))))


(defn freq-seq
  [sdb prefix prefix-support min-sup frequent-seqs]
  (if ((complement empty?) prefix) (swap! fs conj [prefix prefix-support]))
  (let [lf (locally-frequents sdb min-sup)]
(if (empty? lf) nil
                (for [[item sup] lf] (freq-seq (project-sdb sdb (str prefix item)) (str prefix item) sup min-sup @fs)))))

(defn mine-freq-seqs
  [sdb min-sup]
  (freq-seq sdb "" 0 min-sup @fs))
```

running it first

```
(mine-freq-seqs ["CAABC" "ABCB" "CABC" "ABBCA"] 2)
```

then deref-ing the atom
`(deref fs)`

yields

```
#{["B" 4]
  ["BC" 4]
  ["AB" 4]
  ["CA" 3]
  ["CAC" 2]
  ["AC" 4]
  ["ABC" 4]
  ["CAB" 2]
  ["A" 4]
  ["CABC" 2]
  ["ABB" 2]
  ["CC" 2]
  ["CB" 3]
  ["C" 4]
  ["BB" 2]
  ["CBC" 2]
  ["AA" 2]}
```

however `(doall (mine-freq-seqs ["CAABC" "ABCB" "CABC" "ABBCA"] 2) (deref fs))`

just gives `#{}`

What I want is to let the `freq-seq` recurse to completion then get the value of the atom `fs`. So I can call `mine-freq-seq` and have my result returned in the REPL instead of having to manually deref it there.

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.  Can you provide the `lfs` function and add in your atom initialization too?  What are your functions supposed to do?  Can you add input/desired output?

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/themistoklik/4203bb184617c66512b5fdbd49e4d0cc). It's supposed to provide a frequent sequence enumeration. Desired output is already achieved. When I use a doall I get #{}. I will fully edit accordingly when I reach my home machine.

Comment: If you could make the var names a bit more descriptive and possible simplify to a minimal example it would be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AlanThompson see edit.

Comment: When I run this code all I get is:  `(deref fs) => #{["B" 4] ["A" 4] ["C" 4]}
`. It would also help if you could give a verbal description of the desired result; i.e. what is the goal & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it a bit to remove all of the lazy bits (this happens silently in the repl but can be confusing when it changes outside of the repl). Note the changes with `vec`, `mapv`, and `doall`.  At least now I get your result:

```
(def fs (atom #{}))

(defn locally-frequents
  [sdb min-sup]
  (let [uniq-sdb (map (comp frequencies set) sdb)
        freqs    (apply merge-with + uniq-sdb)]
    (->> freqs
      (filter #(<= min-sup (second %)))
      (mapv #(vector (str (first %)) (second %))))))


(defn project-sdb
  [sdb prefix]
  (if (empty? prefix)
    sdb
    (into [] (->> sdb
               (filter #(re-find (re-pattern (str (last prefix))) %))
               (map #(subs % (inc (.indexOf % (str (last prefix))))))
               (remove empty?)))))


(defn freq-seq
  [sdb prefix prefix-support min-sup frequent-seqs]
  (if ((complement empty?) prefix) (swap! fs conj [prefix prefix-support]))
  (let [lf (locally-frequents sdb min-sup)]
    (if (empty? lf)
      nil
      (vec (for [[item sup] lf] (freq-seq (project-sdb sdb (str prefix item)) (str prefix item) sup min-sup @fs))))))

(defn mine-freq-seqs
  [sdb min-sup]
  (freq-seq sdb "" 0 min-sup @fs))

(doall (mine-freq-seqs ["CAABC" "ABCB" "CABC" "ABBCA"] 2))

(deref fs) => #{["B" 4] ["BC" 4] ["AB" 4] ["CA" 3] 
                ["CAC" 2] ["AC" 4] ["ABC" 4] ["CAB" 2] 
                ["A" 4] ["CABC" 2] ["ABB" 2] ["CC" 2] ["CB" 3] 
                ["C" 4] ["BB" 2] ["CBC" 2] ["AA" 2]}
```

I'm still not really sure what the goal is or how/why you get entries like "CABC".

Comment: The goal is given a sequence database (sdb) to provide a frequent sequence enumeration as described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.2704&rep=rep1&type=pdf). "CABC" is a sequence appearing twice, once in "CABC" and once as  a subsequence of "CAABC". The algorithm has applications in data mining and I tried to implement it out of curiosity. With my code to get my result I had to manually deref fs, whereas now I can just add (deref fs) to the end of mine-freq-seqs and deref in there automatically. Your code seems to work, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**First some alternate code** without the atom then a look at why you get the empty return.

A more compact version where the sequences in a string are derived with a reduce rather than the recursion with regex and substr.

Then just do a frequencies on those results.

```
(defn local-seqs
  [s]
  (->> s
       (reduce (fn [acc a] (into acc (map #(conj % a) acc))) #{[]})
       (map #(apply str %))
       (remove empty?)))

(defn freq-seqs
  [sdb min-sup]
  (->> (mapcat local-seqs sdb)
       frequencies
       (filter #(>= (second %) min-sup))
       set))
```

**That's the whole thing!**
I haven't involved an atom because I didn't see a need but add it at the end if freq-seqs if you like.

**For your original question: why the return that you see?**

You are calling `doall` with 2 args, the result of your call and a collection.  doall is a function and not a macro so the deref is performed immediately.

```
(defn doall 
   ;; <snip>
  ([n coll]        ;; you have passed #{} as coll 
   (dorun n coll)  ;; and this line evals to nil
   coll)           ;; and #{} is returned
```

You have passed your result as the n arg and an empty set as the coll (from `(deref fs)`)

Now when `doall` calls `dorun`, it encounters the following:

```
(defn dorun
 ;; <snip>  
([n coll]
 (when (and (seq coll) (pos? n)) ;; coll is #{} so the seq is falesy
   (recur (dec n) (next coll)))) ;; and a nil is returned
```

Since the empty set from `fs` is the second arg (coll) and `and` is a macro, it will be falsey on `(seq coll)`, return nil and then doall returns the empty set that was it's second arg.

Final note:

So that is something that works and why yours failed.  As to how to make yours work, to fix the call above I tried:

```
(do (doall (mine-freq-seqs ["CAABC" "ABCB" "CABC" "ABBCA"] 2))
    (deref fs))
```

That is closer to working but with the recusion in your process, it only forces the eval one level deep.  So you could push the doall deeper into your funcs but I have proposed a completely different internal structure so I will leave the rest to you if you really need that structure.